# Scala: Overriding methods from java interface

Tags: scala, overriding, scala-java-interop

I'm trying to implement a generic java interface in scala. I have looked at:
[How do I extend Java interface containing generic methods in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472311/how-do-i-extend-java-interface-containing-generic-methods-in-scala)
And [Scala: Overriding Generic Java Methods II](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440176/scala-overriding-generic-java-methods-ii)

But still I could not find an answer. Here's the method signature from Spring web:

```
T read(Class<? extends T> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage)
            throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException;
```

I tried the following in scala:

```
 @throws(classOf[IOException])
  @throws(classOf[HttpMessageNotReadableException])
  override def read[T](clazz : Class[_ <: T], inputMessage : HttpInputMessage) : T ={
  }
```

But I get an error saying that this method overrides nothing. If I erase the type by doing:

```
override def read(clazz : Class[_], inputMessage : HttpInputMessage) : AnyRef ={
```

It marks the method as being overwritten. My question is how can I keep type safety here and force it to override the interface method?

Regards

**EDIT**

The spring interface:

```
public interface HttpMessageConverter<T> {

T read(Class<? extends T> clazz,
       HttpInputMessage inputMessage)
       throws IOException,
              HttpMessageNotReadableException
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a link for the source code of the Spring Web where the method you are trying to override/implement resides?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the problem is likely to be that you have added a type parameter to the `read` method, rather than using the type parameter from your class declaration:

```
class MyImpl[T] extends JavaInterface[T] {

  override def read(clazz: Class[_ <: T], ... )

}
```

If we rename your `T` to `U` it becomes clearer what you have done:

```
class MyImpl[T] extends JavaInterface[T] {

  /** U is not T */
  override def read[U](clazz: Class[_ <: U], ... )

}
```

You might also try and sing *"U is not T"* to the tune of REM's *Losing My Religion* to hammer the point home.

Answer (score 0):

In java you have parameterilized interface, but in scala you try to parameterize method.